# Webpack - Copying Files In Development and Production

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-plugin

I wrote a plugin that does something similar to [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin), but provides some extended functionalities that I need. Essentially it simply copies files from `src` to `dist` and performs some operations on them.

It works fine when I run a production build, but in my development build, since i'm using `devServer` and everything is in memory, this doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: dont use dev server.  when u run localhost , you can serve from ./dist and can also do watch / hotswap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution is quite simple. All you need to do is use `compliation.assets` to add more files, instead of something manual like `fs.writeFile`. This will work regardless of whether you're serving the files from memory or from the file system.

For example, the code below will create a file in `path/to/file.ext` with `Hello World!` in it:

```
class MyCoolPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync('MyCoolPlugin', (compilation, done) => {
            compilation.assets['path/to/file.ext'] = {
                source: () => 'Hello World!', // The file's content
                size: () => 10 // Should be the byte size of the content
            };
            done();
        });
    }
}
```